# Retrieving unassigned objects

Tags: clojure, future, meta

I was looking through http.async library and found a piece at this [line](https://github.com/cch1/http.async.client/blob/29fe5fe83f3a13bdecbf3fadddb36a4388ca8473/src/clj/http/async/client/request.clj#L212)

Function `execute-request` returns a map with some promises. The interesting part is where  it returns the map with [`(with-meta ...)`](https://github.com/cch1/http.async.client/blob/29fe5fe83f3a13bdecbf3fadddb36a4388ca8473/src/clj/http/async/client/request.clj#L272) parameters.
It assigns the metadata `:cancel` which is a function that invokes `.cancel` on a response object `(.cancel resp-future true)`.

My question is, what happens to the `resp-future` symbol? Is there any way I can access it, or is it just "lost" and the only way I can interact with it is through `(meta ...)` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you shouldn't need the `resp-future` which is as **future** response as you can see at the [source Java library](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client/blob/42370342853ff7c0cbf6a57a061d16f094af2c4a/api/src/main/java/org/asynchttpclient/AsyncHttpClient.java#L254)

What the function returns is a `resp` map as per documenation says with some extra `meta` information, hence the final [`with-meta`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/with-meta), have a look at the docs and examples.

For completion sake the answer is no, you cannot access the `resp-future` identity, please let us know what are you trying to do to help further.

Regardless of that I encourage you to make sure to understand how [let](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let) works as it's a fundamental Clojure construct.

Comment: Another example is run-jetty function in clojure ring. 
https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-jetty-adapter/src/ring/adapter/jetty.clj#L94
If I don't assign server variable that is returned, the server keeps running but there's no way for me to access the server anymore. I wonder if there's a registry of sort that has these listed, so I can retrieve it and kill gracefully, rather than kill thread or restart repl. Usually, when I develop, a variable returned and I don't assign it, modify code, try to restart to find out the old process is running still.

Comment: Stick to the original question. Indeed to kill it gracefully you should use the function provided through the cancel key on the the _meta_ map. Let's say `(let [your-resp (execute-request a b c ...)
       your-cancel-fn (:cancel (meta your-resp))]
       (your-cancel-fn))`